# How to convert some values in a dict into a list in a clean style in Python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, iteration

My code is like follows, just wondering if there's better way to implement it in Python.

`d[k]` is a `dict`, and `item` is a `list`.

```
if d[k].has_key('v1'):
    item.append(d[k]['v1'])
else:
    item.append('')
if d[k].has_key('v2'):
    item.append(d[k]['v2'])
else:
    item.append('')
if d[k].has_key('e'):
    item.append(d[k]['e'])
else:
    item.append('')
if d[k].has_key('x'):
    item.append(d[k]['x'])
else:
    item.append('')
```

Comment: Does `item` start as an empty list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`dict.get()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) to return a default value if the key is not present:

```
item.append(d[k].get('v1', ''))
```

Here, `d[k].get('v1', '')` returns the value associated with `'v1'` if present in the dictionary, otherwise it'll return `''`.

Combine this with a loop and `list.extend()` and you can add all those keys to the list in one line:

```
item.extend(d[k].get(key, '') for key in ('v1', 'v2', 'e', 'x'))
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
[d[k].get(i,'') for i in ('v1', 'v2', 'e', 'x')]
```

Comment: This creates a new list, not extend an existing.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I can see your point. Thanks for pointing out. I just assumed the list he's creating is just for this purpose. He don't even explain if he need more keys than those in the tuple.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It's not much harder to extend the list, using `original_list +=` or `original_list.extend`.

Comment: @F3AR3DLEGEND: indeed, but that either needs to be made explicit or the OP needs to show that extending is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
item.extend([d[k].get(key, '') for key in ['v1', 'v2', 'e', 'x']])
```

This creates a list with the values and it extends the list `item` with the obtained values.

This makes use of `d[k].get(key, default)` which will use `default` when `key` could not be found in `d[k]`.

Comment: There is no need to use a list comprehension here; a generator expression saves Python the hassle and expense of having to create an intermediary list (which will be discarded after extending).